Unwanted warkspace indicator on top of ubuntu dock
I use Ubuntu (Gnome) 24.04 on my laptop and on my desktop pc.
Recently, only on my laptop, an unpleasant workspace indicator has appeared on top of Ubuntu dock when I scroll to swap workspace. There is a screenshot.
Picture of the issue
I believe this issue has started after installing Gnome Extension Manager on my laptop but I've not touched any settings for Ubuntu Dock. And the issue persist after removing Gnome Extension Manager.
So, I would like to know how it happened and how I can hide it :)
Thanks !
Edit :
Here the result of -s autoremove.
➜  ~ sudo apt -s autoremove 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 1 non mis à jour.
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr_FR) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-fr) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
W: La cible CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1

Also, there is an other screenshot of my issue. Maybe clearer ?
The things with the dots pop on top on my dock each time I use the mousewheel to swap between workspaces.
EDIT 2:

I see it when I use super+pageUp or Down, and it work well, the highlight follow the current workspace.
I dont see it when I scroll on the activity button and it fine.
I see it when I scroll on the dock, and the highlight of the current workspace does not work, like you con see on my screen. -> This is my issue. Scrolling directly on the dock worked like scrolling on the activity button until now.

I already have all extensions disabled.


ah ok and i guess right clicking on it does not show anything?

No, right click does nothing :/.

If you try sudo apt -s autoremove is there anything there? -s is for simulate it will not actually do autoremove

and is scord part of it?

apt -s autoremove give me this :

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 1 non mis à jour.

and multiples warning like this one :
W: La cible Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) est spécifiée plusieurs fois dans /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3 et /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.sources:1
PS:
The : "scrod" behing is not part of it. Just the discord popover :p

Edit your question, dd everything that comes up when you run apt -s autoremove to your question with the code format. I do not know if tit helps with removing the icon but your resluts is a bigger problem,

solving that problem may solve your problem or it may not, the problem is that I do not know what that picture is or where it comes from. Where do you see it, in docks? or just by itself or?

I've edited my post :)

It is normal that this workspace indicator appears when you switch workspaces using the shortcut keys, Super+PgDwn/Up or Ctrl+Alt Left/Right. For me, it does however not appear when switching workspaces through scrolling over the activities button, or using the three-finger gesture on touchpad. Describe more precisely when you see these and when not. To exclude extensions, see if the issue remains after turning off all extensions.

Sure, I've added some details, btw, I've already turned off my extensions.

great, now run sudo apt update and if you do not have anything aginst it  sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt autoremove

since 24.04 is new I run those commands every night
